# Clarification on the proof of the Uniqueness of a Limit

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof from the second edition of Elementary Analysis by Ross for the Uniqueness of a Limit that I am following along with I have so far:

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. $\lim s_n = s \implies \exists N_1$ such that $\forall n > N_1$ $|s_n - s| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. $\lim s_n = t \implies \exists N_2$ such that $\forall n > N_2$ $|s_n - t| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let $N = max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then $\forall n > N$ we apply the Triangle Inequality and have $|s -t| = |(s - s_n) + (s_n - t)| \leqslant |s - s_n| + |s_n - t| \leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon \implies |s - t| < \epsilon \forall \epsilon > 0$.

Up to this point everything makes sense. What confuses me is what follows after where they state that "it follows $|s - t| = 0$" Why does it follow that it is equal to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof you have written down basically proves the statement

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, we know that $|s-t|<\epsilon$.

Since you know that $|s-t|\geq 0$, all you need now is to prove the statement:

> If $x\geq 0$ and $x<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, we can conclude $x=0$.

This is easiest to show with contradiction, since if $x\neq 0$, we see that $x>0$, meaning that (if we set $\epsilon=\frac x2$) $x<\frac{x}{2}$ which is absurd.

---

So, since you have the statement I just wrote, and you know that $\forall \epsilon>0:|s-t|<\epsilon$, the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see $|s-t| = 0$ is by getting a contradiction.
So suppose $|s-t| > 0$, as $|s-t| \ge 0$ and $|s-t| \neq 0$. Then from the proof we have that if $\epsilon >0$, then $|s-t| < \epsilon$.
So we may choose a suitable $\epsilon >0$ to find a contradiction. If we take $\epsilon = |s -t| >0$, we have $|s-t| < \epsilon = |s-t|$, which is a contradiction.

So we cannot have $|s-t| >0$, therefore we have $|s-t| =0$.

Comment: Why are we allowed to choose $\epsilon = |s - t|$ to show that $|s - t| = 0$? I know that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary but that just seems like a convenient choice. How would we go about showing that $|s - t| = 0$ directly for example?

Comment: @PhysicsLemur Because you have already proven the statement $\forall \epsilon>0: |s-t|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @PhysicsLemur By taking the infinum on both sides of $|s-t| < \epsilon$ over all $\epsilon > 0$, we have $0 \le |s-t| = \inf_{\epsilon > 0 } \{ |s-t|\} \le \inf_{\epsilon > 0} \{ \epsilon \} = 0$.